# Beneficiary IRAs and Required Minimum Distributions

Tags: retirement, ira, rmd

If you receive a (non-spousal) Beneficiary-traditional IRA as a beneficiary due to death, is there a way to avoid taking a Required Minimum Distribution until your own retirement age?  Or are you always required to take an RMD regardless of your current age?

Comment: an interesting corollary of a good answer to this question may answer these questions: Can my kids inherit my IRA and not take distributions until **they** turn 70 1/2? Can they leave the unused part of the IRA to their kids on the same condition? Can taxes be thus deferred indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IRS does not let you defer withdrawals from a traditional IRA inherited from someone other than your spouse until your retirement age.

[IRS Pub 590](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch01.html#en_US_publink1000230753)

> If you inherit a traditional IRA from
>   anyone other than your deceased
>   spouse, you cannot treat the inherited
>   IRA as your own. This means that you
>   cannot make any contributions to the
>   IRA. It also means you cannot roll
>   over any amounts into or out of the
>   inherited IRA. However, you can make a
>   trustee-to-trustee transfer as long as
>   the IRA into which amounts are being
>   moved is set up and maintained in the
>   name of the deceased IRA owner for the
>   benefit of you as beneficiary.
>
> Like the original owner, you
>   generally will not owe tax on the
>   assets in the IRA until you receive
>   distributions from it. You must begin
>   receiving distributions from the IRA
>   under the rules for distributions that
>   apply to beneficiaries.
>
> ...
>
> If the
>   beneficiary is an individual, to
>   figure the required minimum
>   distribution for 2010, divide the
>   account balance at the end of 2009 by
>   the appropriate life expectancy from
>   Table I (Single Life Expectancy) in
>   Appendix C

Answer (score 1):

One note to add to Alex' - The RMD divisor for a beneficiary is decremented by one each year, the table is not consulted each year as an over 70-1/2 account holder (of own account) would. A small, but important, distinction.