# Required minimum distribution (RMD) for inherited IRA—how long?

Tags: ira, rmd

My wife inherited an IRA from her late mother.  At the time, wife was 66 and MIL was 88.  Another [QA](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/beneficiary-iras-and-required-minimum-distributions) says RMD (for MIL) starts at 70½ but the manager of a different investment we have says it starts at 73.  We were told by MIL’s trustee that we are required to withdraw all of it within ten years.

**Is the ten years the remaining time on MIL's distributions, or is it always ten years for any heir?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten years is standard withdrawal time limit for inherited retirement accounts in the US. If you take longer, you may be subject to additional taxes.

Comment: Is that also true even if the original owner passed at age fifty?  (Not the case with us, just curious.)

Comment: @WGroleau yes, it is true in that case as well. There are exceptions (for spouses, children, or too close an age), but the general rule is that the inherited IRA must be distributed within 10 years after passing.